# Styled Components v4 refObject

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-ref

I am following how the docs from styled-components have explained to use `refs` in v4 of the library here: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#refs

However, this does not actually seem to work. The ref prop complains about the wrong type being used when just creating a `React.RefObject` and setting it to the `ref` on the styled-component.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
const _Wrapper = styled.div`
position: relative;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
padding: 0px 48px;`;
```

Then I have created a refObject and intialized it in my contructor:

`this.flyoutRef = React.createRef();`

Now when setting this to the ref on the styled-component, it will not start and also shows an error:

`<_Wrapper ref={this.flyoutRef} >{children}</_Wrapper>`

There error showing from TS is this:

`Type 'Ref<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'string | (string & ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void)) | (string & RefObject<HTMLDivElement>) | (((instance: Component<ThemedOuterStyledProps<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, any>, any, any> | null) => void) & string) | ... 6 more ... | undefined'.`

As per the docs from styled-components I am implementing this exactly how it shows. I have even tried to use the `forwardRef` as various examples have shown, but the error continues to be the same.

Here is how I have constructed the styled-component with forwardRef:

```
const Div = ({ innerRef, ...props}: any) => <div innerRef={innerRef} {...props} />;

const Forwarded = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <Div {...props} innerRef={ref} />
));

const _Wrapper = styled(Forwarded)`
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0px 48px;
`;
```

And I am still using it the same as before:

`<_Wrapper ref={this.flyoutRef} >{children}</_Wrapper>`

This now show this error:

`Type 'Ref<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type '(string & ((instance: {} | null) => void)) | (string & RefObject<{}>) | (((instance: Component<ThemedOuterStyledProps<WithOptionalTheme<RefAttributes<{}>, any>, any>, any, any> | null) => void) & ((instance: {} | null) => void)) | ... 4 more ... | undefined'.`

So are the docs from styled-components wrong? Or am I missing something that needs to be forwarded here? I would really appreciate clarification on what's going on here, thank you in advance for the help.

Versions:

styled-components: 4.1.3

react: 16.8.3

Comment: Could you make a [mcv example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? The error you mentioned couldn't be reproduced, this example uses the same version of styled-components & reactjs as yours but it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/54kv62p2nl

Comment: @DerekNguyen It appears that I had an outdated version of the `@types/styled-components` and updating the typings seems to fix the issue. Beware updating past `@types/styled-components@4.1.7` can break some things as they included `@types/react-native` in the styled-components typings. Issue shown here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33311

Comment: @DerekNguyen Thank you for the code sandbox though, that showed me that I was on an outdated typings version.

Comment: Yep, typing styled-components is not a fun experience. Glad you got your problem fixed!